# Joining Two Tables in Python MapReduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to join two tables in a mapreduce job that I am working on. I have two tables that I am joining using one table to fill the other.

Please note that I was following the example (Part 1: Joining) from this [Blog](https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2016/02/09/python-tutorial.html) so you can visit the blog if interested.

Goal: I want to associate a location to each purchase.

> The Mapper reads both datasets and distinguishes them by the number of fields in each row. Transaction records have 5 fields, users have only 4.

> The mapper does two things:

> - For transactions - Extract the user_id and product_id
> - For users - Extract the user_id and the location
> - The mapper outputs three fields: user_id, product_id, location

Here are the two datasets which I will read using sys.stdin:

```
"users.txt" dataset
id   email        language location
1   matthew@test.com    EN  US
2   matthew@test2.com   EN  GB
3   matthew@test3.com   FR  FR

"transaction.txt" dataset    
tran-id prod-id user-id purch-amt item-desc
1          1      1          300    a jumper
2          1      2          300    a jumper
3          1      2          300    a jumper
4          2      3          100    a rubber chicken
5          1      3          300    a jumper
```

The mapper.py code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Setting some defaults
        user_id = ""
        product_id = "-"
        location = "-"

        line = line.strip()
        splits = line.split("\t")
        if len(splits) == 5: # Transactions have more columns than users
           user_id = splits[2]
           product_id = splits[1]
        else:
            user_id = splits[0]
            location = splits[3]
        print (('%s\t%s\t%s') % (user_id,product_id,location))
```

The above mapper creates an output like this:

```
1       1       -
1       -       US
2       1       -
2       1       -
2       -       GB
3       1       -
3       2       -
3       -       FR
```

> Now in the reducer, I want to this. For each new user the Reducer will first remember  that user’s location and then add this location to the transactions.

The reducer.py is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import string

last_user_id = None
cur_location = "-"

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    user_id,product_id,location = line.split("\t")

    if not last_user_id or last_user_id != user_id:
        last_user_id = user_id
        cur_location = location
    elif user_id == last_user_id:
        location = cur_location
        print (('%s\t%s') % (product_id,location))
```

The above reducer produces this output:

```
-       -
1       -
-       -
2       -
-       -
```

But the output I am expecting is:

```
1   FR
1   GB
1   GB
1   US
2   FR
```

I am sure the problem is in the reducer script, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You should really consider using Pyspark or Pig/Hive to join tabular data. As mentioned in your last two posts, tracking "last id" isn't really the best use case for mapreduce

Comment: Your code seems unchanged from the blog, and you've not told us what command you're using to run both scripts... and there are 2 mapper scripts and two reducer scripts to join the data.... Did you try running the code from the repo rather than the blog? https://github.com/rathboma/hadoop-framework-examples/tree/master/streaming-python/ut_join

Comment: I was able to finally solve the problem by mapping the rows with the country information to those that do not have using the key. This has really made my weekend because I have sat on this for weeks. Thank you for your help.